# How to read hidden ids Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to read collection when there is no field present in a node?

For example I have collection data like below:

```
tags > tagid1 > postId > { createdBy : 'user1' }
tags > tagid2 > postId > { createdBy : 'user1' }
tags > tagid3 > postId > { createdBy : 'user1' }
```

Where I am trying to read the tags collection it is not giving any data.

```
const g = await db.collection('tags').get();
g.size // 0  - but it has three sub element tagid1, tagid2, tagId3 (these ids are dynamic)
```

Is there any way we can read collection when childern's don't have direct element in it?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `0` because in your `tags` collection there no actual documents. The `tagid1`, `tagid2`, `tagId3` and so on, do not exist. Those documents (tag objects) do not exist because you didn't create them at all. What you did do, is to create a subcollection under a document that never existed in the first place. With other words, you merely "reserved" an `id` for a document in your `tags` collection and then you have created a subcollection under it. Generally speaking, you should only create subcollections of documents that actually do exist.

Keep in mind that in Firestore documents and subcollections don't work like filesystem files and directories. If you create a subcollection under a document, it doesn't implicitly create any parent documents. Subcollections are not tied in any way to a parent document.

If you want to get the actual number of documents, create under each tag object at least a property that holds a value.

Comment: Hi Sathishkumar! Can I help you with other informations? If you think that my answer helped you, please consider accepting it. I'd appreciate it. Thanks!